# The local variable driver may not have been initialized selenium

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a new function and I'm unable to use a driver within the function

I'm getting this message "The local variable driver may not have been initialized "

In the main I have no problem using the driver

````
    {
        WebDriver driver;
    WebElement check = driver.findElement(By.id("conditions_agree"));
    boolean selected_value = check.isSelected();
    if(!selected_value)
    check.click();
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your code is java, not javascript.

For local variable (variable that is declared in a method), java requires user to initialize before using, so you can modify like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: I want to write down a function within the CLASS

Once I do as you wrote it opens a new page for me and I want to call the function on a page that is already open

Comment: please edit your question, provide more code and clarify your intent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've created a driver instance in the main method as you stated and next, you are using a non-static block where you again tried to use `WebDriver driver` instead of it use the previously created instance

```
public class AutmationTesting {
 static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args){
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Path to driver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

{
  //try to directly access the methods and not by writing the WebDriver driver; otherwise, it'll show an initialization error

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("element_xpath"));
    WebElement check = driver.findElement(By.id("conditions_agree"));
    boolean selected_value = check.isSelected();
    if(!selected_value)
    check.click();
}
}
}
```